# Will installing WinZip 22 on a server create a security vulnerability?

Tags: .net, windows-server

I've recently requested a WinZip v22 with command line installation on a Windows POC/Dev server that we're using to pilot an application that is written in .Net.

In the application there is functionality that hooks into WinZip using:

```
ProcessStartInfo("c:\winzip.exe")
```

When a request was made to install WinZip 22 on the server, an inquiry was made as to whether this would pose a security vulnerability.

I searched [CVE Details](https://www.cvedetails.com/vendor/787/Winzip.html) and [Mitre](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=WINZIp) but the  last issue seems to be in 2008.

Thanks in advance for any insight on this.

Comment: So to be clear, your question is: Will installing WinZip 22 on a server create a security vulnerability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No if you patch Winzip frequently.

Yes if you don't patch it.

This answer applies to all software on a server not just Winzip.  Only put software on a server that is required in order to reduce risk and attack surface.